# CSS Styling of Single Menu Item

Tags: css, menu, navigation

On this site: https://new.fbhsfoundation.com/give-now/ I have figured out how to add a custom style for a single nav but I want to make the background surround the text (I.e. more padding left and right of the yellow color) but I can't figure it out.

This is the code I tried and then applied the custom CSS to the menu item but it only did the background color not the padding:

`.yellow li.menu-item a { padding 5px; }`

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find and remove the padding property for .menu li and add a padding style for the .yellow class.

```
.menu li{
    min-width: 36px;
    margin: 0 12px;
    /*padding: 0*/
}

.yellow{
    background-color: #ffe400;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

or better still, use the id of the list element(li) to add the padding style.

```
li#menu-item-46{
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 12 pixels of padding instead of the 12px margin.

```
.menu li {
    min-width: 36px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 12px;
}
```